# LINQ Get Count of 2nd level detail table

Tags: linq, count, group-by, nested, subquery

I'm trying to get the count of records from a detail table, and it's detail table in LINQ and I'm hitting a road block.

Lets say I have 3 tables in this structure:

```
Header
    Detail
        Items
```

I would like to see all Header items with the count of Detail and the count of it's Items.

```
from h in Header select new {
  h.Name,
  h.IsEnabled,
  DetailCount = h.Details.Count(),
  ItemCount = h.Details.Items.Count() <---- Here's the problem
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
from h in Header select new {
  h.Name,
  h.IsEnabled,
  DetailCount = h.Details.Count(),
  ItemCount = h.Details.SelectMany(d => d.Items).Count()
}
```

Or if you prefer you could sum the items count of each detail:

```
from h in Header select new {
  h.Name,
  h.IsEnabled,
  DetailCount = h.Details.Count(),
  ItemCount = h.Details.Sum(d => d.Items.Count())
}
```

Comment: Is there a good resource on the web for learning these ins and outs?

Comment: @Eric, probably, but I don't know where... the best way to learn is to dig through the MSDN documentation, and practice of course ;)

Comment: I also suggest reading the excellent [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx) series by Jon Skeet. It's an independent implementation of Linq for educational purposes. Each Linq operator is explained in great detail, so at the end you should have a much better understanding of how Linq works.